# Системы счисления

Tags: информатика

Есть задача:

> Сколько существует различных систем счисления в которых число 40 оканчивается на 0.

Как решать подобные задачки ?

Comment: если взять в расчёт, что различных систем счисления существует бесконечное множество, и допустить, что число 40 оканчивается на 0 в N системах из этого множества, то получаем, что таких систем ... бесконечное множество

Comment: Возможно задание не правильно написано , оно взято из пробного варианта ЕГЭ , но ответ на это задание должел быть записан в виде числа

Comment: чем ни число - **∞**

Comment: @spectre очевидно, что это число ограничено, потому что при N>40 число 40 будет обозначено неким одним символом, так как 40 будет уже не числом, а цифрой.

Comment: скорее всего ваш ответ абсолютно верен, просто я взял в расчёт, что СС - это всего лиш форма записи числа, которых достаточно много...

Comment: @spectre в задаче скорее всего под нулем подразумевается первая цифра счисления с которой начинается счет.

Comment: я придумал новую СС, вот она 0, 1, 4, 9,...1521, 1600, 1681... в ней число 40 заканчивается на ноль

Comment: Мне кажется, Вашу СС можно назвать СС лишь условно, по идее в системе счисления число обозначается только одним знаком, иначе возникнут противоречия в записи. Представьте например, что 1515 это 16-ричное число аналогичное FF, но только по другому записанное.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На ноль оно заканчивается только в тех системах счисления, основание которых является делителем 40.
Это 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 40

Comment: Примечание.  
При условии, что в единичной системе счисления  
1=0  
2=00  
3=000  
4=0000

Answer (score 0):

Это можно легко самому понять. Во превых, все системы исчиления с базой выше 40 уже не подходят, так как число 40 в них не заполнит полный разряд.
Число подозреваемых сузилось до 40.
Чтобы число оканчивалось на 0 нужно чтобы наше число заполняло нижний разряд("единицы").
Это возможно

в 40-чной системе. Заполнит 1 раз (число 10)

в 20-чной системе. Заполнит 2 раза (число 20)

в 10-чной системе. Заполнит 4 раза (число 40)

в 5-чной системе. Заполнит 8 раза (число 130)

в 4-чной системе. Заполнит 10 раз (число 220)

в 2-чной системе. Заполнит 20 раз (число 101000)

в 1-чной системе. Заполнит 40 раз (число с сорока нулями: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 )

и т.д.